# Render only one children item

Tags: reactjs

I create a `SidebarItem` component:

```
import React from 'react'

function SidebarItem(props) {
  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      className="text-turquoise-700 hover:bg-turquoise-100 hover:text-gray-900 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md"
    >
      {props.children}
      {props.text}
    </a>
  )
}

export { SidebarItem }
```

I'm using it like this:

```
<SidebarItem text="Calendar">
  <svg
    className="text-turquoise-200 group-hover:text-turquoise-600 mr-3 h-6 w-6"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"
    />
  </svg>
</SidebarItem>
```

How can I ensure I can only pass exactly one `<svg>` element as children?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but have you looked at [React.Children.count](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrencount) and [React.Children.only](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly)?

Comment: Throw an error if `props.children.length > 1`?

Comment: @rayhatfield thanks for the hint. Didn't know about `React.Children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @rayfield I solved it that way:

<s>`{React.Children.only(props.children)} {React.Children.forEach(props.children, (x) => { if (x.type !== 'svg') throw new Error('only children elements of type <svg> are valid') })}`</s>

```
const item = React.Children.only(children)
  if (item.type !== 'svg')
    throw new Error('only children items of type <svg> are valid')
```

Comment: `React.Children.only` returns the child. No need to iterate. `const x = React.Children.only(props.children)`.